# Ruby on Rails: Allowing separate Calendars to share the same Event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

I'm having some trouble with the theory (and code) behind my events creator. A quick overview:
I have `Customers` (the users) who each own a `Calendar`. A `Calendar` `belongs_to` a `Customer` Each `Calendar` `has_many` `Events`, and an `Event belongs_to` a `Calendar`:

```
#customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_one :calendar, :dependent => :destroy
...
end 

#calendar.rb
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy    
end

#event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar

end
```

When a Customer fills in a form in `events\new.html.erb` the Events_controller's `create` action picks up the info from the form, including an array `id_array` of each participant Customer that the creator of the event wished to be involved.

So far, I have made it so that the events_controller iterates through the array and creates a corresponding `Event` for each of the participating customer's `Calendar`:

```
def create

    @calendar = current_customer.calendar
    @newevent = @calendar.events.build(event_params) #creates event in creator's calendar

    @participant_ids = params[:id_array]

    @participant_ids.each do |item| #iterates through id array, finds corresponding customer and creates event
      @participant = Customer.find(item)
      @part_calendar = @participant.calendar 
      @part_event = @part_calendar.events.build(event_params) #adds event to participant's calendar
    end

    if @newevent.save
      redirect_to '/main' #'/main/#{@calendar.id}'
    else
      redirect_to '/compose'
      end

  end
```

However, this is clearly not satisfactory, because none of these events created are **connected to each other** at all. I would like to know what the best most efficient and rubyish way is to allow all these Customer's Calendars to **share** the event (or share a unique identifier). This is so that if the creator decides to delete the event, it will be deleted from all participating calendars.

```
Here is also my event db migrate file for reference:

class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|

      t.timestamps
      t.references :calendar, foreign_key: true

      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.date :day
      t.datetime :starts_at
      t.datetime :ends_at
      t.string :location

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would add a join table between events and calendars, and make it "has_many :through" in both directions, rather than "event belongs_to calendar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the `Event` self referenced: An event will have many events and belongs to an event:

#### Model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :event, class_name: "Event"
end
```

You will have to add `event_id` to your migration as an `integer`

#### Controller

```
  def create
    @calendar = current_customer.calendar
    @newevent = @calendar.events.build(event_params) #creates event in creator's calendar

    if @newevent.save
      # We wait until it's saved because we need its id
      @participant_ids = params[:id_array]
      @participant_ids.each do |item|
        @participant = Customer.find(item)
        @part_calendar = @participant.calendar 
        # We merge the newly created event id to the params
        @part_event = @part_calendar.events.
          build(event_params.merge(event_id: @newevent.id))
        @part_event.save
      end
      redirect_to '/main' #'/main/#{@calendar.id}'
    else
      redirect_to '/compose'
    end
  end
```

This way you will have this:

Let's say that `customer` has a calendar and through your form you created an `event` and also selected other customers to be part of this `event`:

The `current_customer` will have new `event`, each of the other `customer`s you selected will have a new `event` ( which have a shared parent `event` which is the new `event` of the `current_customer`). This way:

- The newly created `event` will have a children `events` via `event.events` as you wiched
- If you destroy the `event` of the `current_customer`, all it's children `event`s will be destroy
- You can access a parent event of a particular `event` via `event.event`

Comment: ok, will removing "belongs_to :calendar" have any effect on another other methods? Such as in the calendar show view?

Comment: You do not have to remove anything.

Comment: oh ok, so my events model will have 3 associative code lines? Also, when adding event_id to the migration, do I declare it as t.string event_id or is it more complicated than that? thanks

Comment: I am getting an error on the line  @part_event = @part_calendar.events.build(event_params) #adds event to participant's calendar
saying undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass, why am I getting this?